# Iteração While com data e hora

Tags: java, mysql

Como organizar o método `JAVA` abaixo, para obter a saída conforme o exemplo.Tenho um array de horários (seriam entrada e saída), e preciso associar estes horários a um intervalo de datas, enquanto estava com entrada e saída no mesmo dia consegui fazer, mas no modelo abaixo, a entrada ocorre em um dia e a saída no outro, e um dia antes e um depois da folga só tem uma entrada ou uma saída...

exemplo de saída que preciso:

```
    1/1/2018 23:00
    2/1/2018 23:00
    2/1/2018 06:00
    3/1/2018 23:00
    3/1/2018 06:00
    4/1/2018 06:00
    5/1/2018 00:00 (folga)
    5/1/2018 00:00 (folga)
    6/1/2018 23:00
    7/1/2018 23:00
    7/1/2018 06:00
    8/1/2018 23:00
    8/1/2018 06:00
    9/1/2018 06:00
    10/1/2018 00:00 (folga)
```

Método:

```
 public void teste5(){

        String []hora = new String[8];
        String []result = new String[10];
        int dia = 1;
        int i=0;



        hora[0]="23:00";
        hora[1]="06:00";
        hora[2]="23:00";
        hora[3]="06:00";
        hora[4]="23:00";
        hora[5]="06:00";
        hora[6]="00:00";
        hora[7]="00:00";         

        while(dia < 10){ //aqui será definido um intervalo de datas


            result[i] = dia+"/1/2018"+hora[i];
            System.out.println(result[i]);

           dia++;
        }

    }
```

Depois de conseguir fazer funcionar este método vou armazenar no `MySQL` conforme abaixo:

```
  entrada              saida
1/1/2018 23:00     2/1/2018 06:00
2/1/2018 23:00     3/1/2018 06:00
3/1/2018 23:00     4/1/2018 06:00
5/1/2018 00:00     5/1/2018 00:00 
6/1/2018 23:00     7/1/2018 06:00
7/1/2018 23:00     8/1/2018 06:00
8/1/2018 23:00     9/1/2018 06:00
10/1/2018 00:00    10/1/2018 00:00
11/1/2018 23:00    12/1/2018 06:00
```

Comment: Cadê o array de data? Só vejo um array de string com horas. O código nao condiz com a duvida.

Comment: A data eu consigo associar depois, no lugar do "dia" do exemplo.

Comment: O seu problema envolve a data, sem ela, seu codigo nao faz sentido algum  com sua duvida.

Comment: Mas o mesmo que se pode fazer com o "dia" do exemplo, pode se fazer com a data..acrescentar um dia por exemplo, e unir com o horário. Tenho somente um array com os horários, que é fixo, a data será definida dentro do 'While'.

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa nao, inteiro é inteiro, data é data, sao formas totalmente diferentes de organizar, e como seu objetivo e listar, faz toda a diferença ser um inteiro ou uma data a ser adicionado na hora.

Comment: Mas a data não é fixa, eu não sei como montar isso dentro do while, a data poderá ser qualquer período, entre 01/01/2018 a 10/01/2018 por exemplo ou qualquer outro. Dentro deste período tenho que distribuir o array de horários repetidamente, com entrada as 23:00 e saída as 06:00 do outro dia.

Comment: Cara, exemplifica melhor tua dúvida. Atualmente não tá dando pra inferir muita coisa sobre as horas "23" e "06", só que pode ser folga de um dia pro outro.. Tem algum intervalo padrão para definir entre os dias para especificar uma folga ou algo assim... Explica melhor.. E é melhor lidar com os tipos específicos para Datas, Horas e Intervalos; Utilizar inteiros e strings para isso acaba complicando, sem falar que é gambiarra e adição de complexidade..

Comment: Concordo com o @Marlysson. Data e hora sao representacoes temporais, nao da pra tratar isso a nao ser como "representacoes temporais". Isso que voce está tentando fazer soa como gambiarra mesmo. Talvez fazendo da maneira correta, tratando ambos como temporais, até fique mais facil te ajudar e voce a lidar com o problema.

Comment: Java ja tem inumeras APIs para lidar tanto com somente data quanto com somente tempo, assim como tem tambem para lidar com ambos ao mesmo tempo, pra que reinventar a roda?

Comment: @Marlysson - Sim existe um intervalo fixo para folga - exemplo 3x1, 3 dias trabalhados e um de folga, sempre desta forma a iteração, sempre entre 23:00 de um dia até as 06:00 do outro dia, mas realmente, acho que vai ficar mais fácil e correto utilizar alguma API nativa para fazer isso ao invés de ir somando datas dentro do while, vou tentar refazer o método aqui .